# Empty expression to format axis labels

Tags: r, plot, expression

I am using the `grid`package to draw some graph, and use its ability to format axis ticks via expressions.

I am unable, however, to figure out, how to display formatted labels for only a subset of ticks.

```
require(grid)
grid.newpage()
xg <- xaxisGrob(at=c(.1,.5,1),
                label = expression(10^-1, .5, 10^0),
                main=FALSE)

layout <- grid.layout(nrow=1, ncol=1,
                          heights = unit.c(unit(.25, "npc")),
                          widths = unit.c(unit(.25, "npc"))
                          )

pushViewport(viewport(layout=layout))
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=1, 
                      layout.pos.col=1))

grid.draw(xg)
```

I would like not to show any label for the 0.5 tick. If I replace `.5` with `NULL`or `''`,or the like, the label at 1 is also omitted, without an error.

Comment: Your example does not plot anything on my system (except a line at the very top of the graphics device).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry, `heights` argument was wrong, should plot now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
xg <- xaxisGrob(at=c(.1,.5,1),
                label = expression(10^-1, phantom(0), 10^0),
                main=FALSE)
```

[image: resulting plot]